# Css to make specific html a two column layout

Tags: html, css

Having the current html:

```
<div id="divFiltros" class="DivFiltrosInforme">
    <div>
        <div>
            <span>FILTROS SELECCIONADOS</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Fecha desde:</span><span id="spFiltrosFechaDesde">01/01/2012</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Fecha hasta:</span><span id="spFiltrosFechaHasta">01/01/2012</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Clientes:</span><span id="spFiltrosClientes">Clientex</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span>Sección:</span><span id="spFiltrosSeccion">Cualquiera</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
  .DivFiltrosInforme
{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

    .DivFiltrosInforme > div
    {
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 2px;
    }

        .DivFiltrosInforme > div > div
        {
            padding-top: 5px;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }

            .DivFiltrosInforme > div > div:first-child > span
            {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 14pt;
            }

            .DivFiltrosInforme > div > div > span
            {
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 10pt;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
            }
```

What CSS rules would you add in order to make it a 2 column layout (Excluding the first div which is the tittle). Take into account that the number of divs (the ones that contain two spans) will variate. Preferably i would like only to change the CSS...

Comment: You mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/4SYZ4/

Comment: This would work and seems IE compatible, if you put it as an answer i will accept it

Comment: I've added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4SYZ4/)

All I've done was added `width: 50%` and `float:left` to this rule, but added a `:not` filter to filter out the title (whilst giving title an id of title of course):

```
.DivFiltrosInforme > div > div:not(#title)
{
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the **[CSS3 multicol module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/)**.

It has bad IE-support though. All other browsers are [already capable](http://caniuse.com/#search=multic).

Comment: Yes it would be the desired one but without IE-support its not valid for our case (we export the html to excel & word in some cases and they only support usually the styles that work on IE)

Answer (score 0):

Umm, I think you can use floats on the two divs(two column) and then at the parent div, make the overflow:hidden.

I found your codes very complicated (for me) Lolz

Here's a simple code for a two column layout.

[Example layout @ jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/JuvarAbrera/S4q7g/1/) <-- Click xD

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
    border:1px solid red;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden
}

#left {
    background:blue;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    color:red;
}

#right {
    background:black;
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    color:white;
}
```

​

Comment: well the simple version is that we have a list of filters displayed (one div per filter) the list is variable so we need to make it two column dinamically, not static like your example...maybe playing with nth-child(even) and nth-child(odd) but ignoring the tittle div (first one)...its difficult yes...thats why we asked the experts ;)